# Ed Thorp Wilmott Articles

Tags: quant-trading-strategies

I've been really enjoying Ed Thorp's autobiography, and it makes me want to revisit some of his old Wilmott articles, listed here:

http://www.wilmottwiki.com/wiki/index.php?title=Thorp,_Edward

Wilmott columns

- What I Knew and When I Knew It – Part 1, September 2002, pp. 44-45. Reprinted in Noesis, the Journal of the Mega Society, Issue #177, June 2005.
- What I Knew and When I Knew It – Part II, December 2002, pp. 44-45. Reprinted in Noesis, the Journal of the Mega Society 
  What I Knew and When I Knew It – Part II , January 2003, pp. 42-43. Reprinted in Noesis, the Journal of the Mega Society
- The Distribution of Stock Price Changes – Part I, March 2003, pp. 26-27.
- The Distribution of Stock Price Changes – Part II, May 2003, pp. 42-43.
- How Rich is Rich? – Part 1, July 2003, pp. 44-45.
- How Rich is Rich? – Part II, September 2003, pp. 32-33.
- A Million Dollars for Mathematics – Part I, November 2003, pp. 34-35.
- A Million Dollars for Mathematics – Part II, January 2004, pp. 38-40.
- A Million Dollars for Mathematics – Part III, March 2004, pp. 32-33.
- A Theory of Inefficient Markets – Part I, May 2004, pp. 38-40.
- A Theory of Inefficient Markets – Part II, July 2004, pp. 46-47.
- Statistical Arbitrage – Part I, August 2004, pp. 44-45.
- Statistical Arbitrage – Part II, November 2004, pp. 48-49.
- Statistical Arbitrage – Part III, January 2005, pp. 36-37
- Statistical Arbitrage – Part IV, March 2005, pp. 66-67
- Statistical Arbitrage – Part V, May 2005, pp. 46-47
- Statistical Arbitrage – Part VI, July 2005, pp. 34-36
- Inefficient Markets, September 2005, pp. 36-38
- Bridge With Buffett. November 2005
- Berkshire Hathaway. January 2006

A couple of the later ones are still available on the Wilmott website, and he has the one on start arb on his own website, but the rest are very hard to find can anyone point me to some online copies?

Kind Regards

Baz

Comment: Hello Bazman,  I too have been reading Ed's book. I bacame a big fan after reading his segment in Hedge Fund Market Wizards. He use to have these articles on his site, but i just checked back and they were removed but you can find some useful articles: http://www.edwardothorp.com/articles/

Comment: @Rime this is an answer, not a comment

Comment: Are they hard to find if you're ready to pay or are they hard to find for free?

Comment: Thanks Rime, but only one of the Wilmott articles article is available on the website at the moment. The articles are hard to find full stop.

Answer (score 4):

I too have been reading Ed's book. I bacame a big fan after reading his segment in Hedge Fund Market Wizards. He use to have these articles on his site, but i just checked back and they were removed but you can find some useful articles: http://www.edwardothorp.com/articles/

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a free resource but it's still relatively inexpensive, if you sign up for the [Wilmott Magazine](https://wilmott.com/category/magazine/) you can get the archives for all of the past issues of the magazine. I've verified it myself. It cost me $301.79 as of writing.

[image]